# Releasing a vassal as a vassal?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

I am playing as a Japan Daimyo which basically is a vassal of Japan with the speciality that a Daimyo can declare war on and annex other Daimyos. However it is impossible to vassalise them, because they are a subject nation of Japan.

Now I noticed that I can release them as vassals after completely annexing them. Will this really make them my vassal (I doubt it considering that I am a subject nation myself) or will this make them independent **from me** again and "only" a vassal/Daimyo of Japan?

I always played under the assumption that a vassal cannot have vassals of his own, so I am a bit confused what will happen.

I would try it, but I am playing Ironman and don't really want to screw up my Achievement hunt for "The Chrysanthemum Throne".

Comment: In EU3 and earlier, I know it was possible for vassals to have vassals. I haven't tested in EU4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tested this under the latest version of 1.9 on non-Ironman by playing as a Japanese daimyo, annexing another daimyo through console, and releasing them through the "Release Subjects" dialog. They remain your vassals, even after monthly/yearly ticks.

[image: Hosokawa is a vassal of Yamana.]

Comment: If you say "they remain your vassals", who is "they"? Your vassal or the vassal of your vassal?

Comment: If you're a daimyo and a vassal of Japan, and you release a daimyo from provinces you own, the released daimyo remains your vassal, and not a vassal of Japan.

Comment: Ah ok, I get it now. My comment didn't make much sense. Has been some time since I posted the question and I got confused about the situation. ;) Thanks for doing the research!

Comment: No worries! (Slightly) better late than never, right?

Answer (score 0):

As of patch 1.4, the released daimyos will become subjects of Japan.

> If you are a daimyo and force another daimyo to release another daimyo, then that daimyo will become a proper vassal of Japan now.

Source: [Patch 1.4 release notes at EU4Wiki](http://www.eu4wiki.com/Patch_1.4#War_.26_Peace).

Comment: Yep, saw that too. That doesn't really answer what happens if you release them yourself though. Forcing an enemy to release a country doesn't make them their Vassal either, so there is a substantial difference between peacefully releasing someone and doing so by war.